# CSS style for ARBONNE text

Tags: css, fonts

I'm making a website for a friend and he wants the text font to be AR BONNIE. Does anyone know the CSS for this? I can't seem to find the font anywhere.

Comment: In addition to the answers given: Be careful with turning a font into a `font-face` or other kind of distributable font without checking the license. The font's license often forbids redistribution like that. You may be much better off with a free/open-source font that looks similar. Finding a  Google web font would be easiest

Answer (score 5):

Go to this site: [onlinefontconverter](http://onlinefontconverter.com/) and create woff, eot, svg and ttf files
and put this in css

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'ARBONNIE';
    src: url('ar-bonnie.eot');
    src: local('☺'),
         url('ar-bonnie.woff') format('woff'), 
         url('ar-bonnie.ttf') format('truetype'), 
         url('ar-bonnie.svg#ARBONNIE') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

and you can set `p { font-family: 'ARBONNIE'; }`

Comment: Only do this if the license for the font allows embedding; many do not.

Answer (score 3):

AR BONNIE is not een valid webfont.(see http://web.mit.edu/jmorzins/www/fonts.html)

There are different types of solutions.

- Use javascript: [sifr](http://wiki.novemberborn.net/sifr/) or [cufon](http://cufon.shoqolate.com/generate/) or [typeface](http://typeface.neocracy.org/)
- Use css3 - [@font-face](http://www.css3.info/preview/web-fonts-with-font-face/) (not supported by all browsers)

Always check if the font is legal for your project. EULA rights...

Comment: just a question: what is a "web font"? Is it different from normal fonts (or any truetype font)?

Comment: "web font" — font installed on a significant number of web users' systems (AKA "font that comes with common operating systems and/or office software")

Answer (score 2):

Andes, from Dafont, is pretty close:

But since its not web font , you have to embed exclusively.

You can also take a look at

http://code.google.com/webfonts

its google web font , you can use in css.

http://www.dafont.com/search.php?psize=m&q=andes

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a font in CSS, you must make sure that all of your visitors have that font installed, or [provide it in an url](http://www.enginetrack.com/news/vol3/css_no15.htm), or display it as a bitmap or via flash.

Answer (score 1):

A great option is using [typeface.js](http://typeface.neocracy.org/). I've not used it myself in any of my sites, but I loved the concept, and the examples they've provided.

Answer (score 0):

AR BONNIE is a replicated version of the Ascender "Plaza" font which was then resold as AR BONNIE.

Click [here](http://www.ascenderfonts.com/font/plaza.aspx) for the Plaza font.